# lxml-html read produces empty list Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xpath, lxml

I am trying to read the two line elements for STRaND-1 from this link: https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/cubesat.txt, so I can track it from a ground station I'm building. I don't really understand how to use the xtree.xpath command an I'd like to learn how.
I'm trying the following code that I found from a similar question asked on here a while ago:

```
import numpy as np
from lxml import html
import requests
line_number = 50
for word in range(0,5):
    page = requests.get("https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/cubesat.txtid=%s" % word)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    print (tree.xpath("//b/text()")
```

This should print the code between the  elements of the html page right? How do I just print from a certain line? Expecially when there is no html prefix before the text that I want?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your request returns you text file, but not HTML document. You can try to request data in different format (JSON, XML) or save it and parse with Python built-in functions as simple file.txt. P.S. I tried to get response both in JSON and XML, and it seem that text is the only available format... But anyway you can try :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. I have been able to obtain the list but am unsure how to read an individual line from it. Any advice?

Comment: Which exact data you want to get?

Comment: The two lines below STRAND-1 (Lines 51 and 52 right now). I want to make two variables from them.

Comment: I also want those variables to be a string. I'm finding that trying to use islice to read the lines after STRAND-1 is troublesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below solution to get required data:

```
import requests

url = "http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/cubesat.txt"
response = requests.get(url)

page_content = response.text
all_lines = [line.strip() for line in page_content.split("\n")]
for index, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    if line == "STRAND-1":
        first_value = all_lines[index + 1]
        second_value = all_lines[index + 2]
        break

print(first_value, "\n", second_value)
```

Output:

```
1 39090U 13009E   18037.58367953  .00000016  00000-0  21168-4 0  9998 
 2 39090  98.5328 245.5663 0008674 331.4360  28.6349 14.35009671259097
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this with help from Andersson. (Thanks a million!)

Using a urllib.request.urlopen, a basic for loop and .decode utf-8 I got it to work. Didn't even need lxml. I know this is far from the most elegant implementation of this logic, and any input on how to clean it up and condense it would be appreciated, but at least it works for me.

My Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


line_number1 = 50
line_number2 = 1

with urlopen("http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/cubesat.txt") as TLEDB:
    i = 1
    for line in TLEDB:
        if i == line_number1:
            break
        i += 1
    line1 = line.decode("utf-8")
    print(line1)

    n = 1
    for line in TLEDB:
        if n == line_number2:
            break
        n += 1
    line2 = line.decode("utf-8")
    print(line2)
```

Thanks again for the help.

L